# Redirect subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns, virtualhost

i've already read all topics here and on google about redirection but i'm a programmer and i cant get it going.  
I have Apache 2.2 installed. The web root is C:\Apache\htdocs. My network admin set me up a local domain that points to the server with Apache. The domain is myPhpApp.ourcompany.local. And this subdomain works, it shows the Apache "It works" page.  
Now i have a website in C:\Apache\htdocs\myPhpApp and i want Apache to redirect the myPhpApp.ourcompany.local to this directory. The URLs should stay while browsing the website always as myPhpApp.ourcompany.local for example: myPhpApp.ourcompany.local/index.php, myPhpApp.ourcompany.local/data.php and so on. 
I dont know how to achieve this? Mod-rewrite, virtual hosts, combination of both?
i have got this and this does not work:

```
<VirtualHost myphpapp.ourcompany.local>
DocumentRoot /myphpapp/
ServerName www.example1.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /myphpapp/  [R]

</VirtualHost>
```

In effect i get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /myphpapp/ on this server.
>   Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
Maybe i forgot to mention: i dont put this into the www root which is C:/Apache/htdocs becuase i have more apps in there. 
i have 3 directories in thdocs: myphpapp, myoldapp, mytestapp. As a target i want to have 3 subdomains that point to each directory.

Comment: About the EDIT. Again, this is not a problem, this is standard web server configuration. one app one directory, so this is NOT a problem.you do not need mod-rewrite or redirects, just simple document root configuration, a document root is the "sites" root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be a combination of Nikola's and cromestant's answers:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/htdocs/myPhpApp"
    ServerName myPhpApp.ourcompany.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Indeed it was: `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.228>
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/htdocs/app1"
   ServerName app1.company.local
    <Directory "C:/Apache/htdocs/app1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a rewrite rule for simple thing as this.
I assume you need following VirtualHost definition

```
<VirtualHost *>

    DocumentRoot /myphpapp/
    ServerName myphpapp.ourcompany.local

</VirtualHost>
```

"VirtualHost *" part tells Apache on which interface and optionally port to listen to.
ServerName tells which domain name will be used to identify this virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Document root in your apache config should point to your directory where you have the app, in what you stated in your question it should be

```
DocumentRoot C:\Apache\htdocs\myPhpApp
```

and that is all.
restart or reload your apache, and test.